# $21$ people in classroom, split into $4$ groups of $4$ and $1$ group of $5,$ probability specified two people together

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Alice and Bob are two students among a class of $21$. Their teacher will randomly divide the class into $4$ groups of $4$ and one group of $5.$ Find the probability that Alice and Bob are put in the same group?

A possible way of solving this problem outlined is to do $(4)(4)(3)$ and $(5)(4),$ add them and divide by $420.$ However, I'm not really sure how this works. If we split the problem into cases of when they are together in a group of $4$ and when they are together in a group of $4,$ for the first case there are $4$ possible groups, but from there why do we have to do $4 \cdot 3?$ If we want the two to be in the same group, then there will be $19$ undetermined spots, and of those we can choose $2$ people to  be in that group of $4,$ to obtain $\tbinom{19}{2} \cdot 4=15504,$ but this is clearly wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I was wondering if there is a easier way of doing this problem instead of computing number of desired possibilities over total possibilities, and instead considering the problem as, since there are $4$ groups of $4,$ then there is a $\tfrac{16}{21}$ possibility of groups of $4,$ and a $\tfrac{5}{21}$ possibility of groups of $5.$ In other words, I am curious if there are any other approaches to the aforementioned one, which I am confused on why it works. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rare problem that is best attacked as probability of events problem rather than enumeration of Combinatorics.

---

Probablity that Alice is at a table of $(4)$ is $\dfrac{16}{21}.$

When that happens, probability that Bob is at the same table is $\dfrac{3}{20}.$

---

Probablity that Alice is at a table of $(5)$ is $\dfrac{5}{21}.$

When that happens, probability that Bob is at the same table is $\dfrac{4}{20}.$

---

Putting this all together, the desired computation is

$$\left[\frac{16}{21} \times \frac{3}{20}\right] + \left[\frac{5}{21} \times \frac{4}{20}\right].$$

Answer (score 2):

The first approach that you mention considers there to be different "orderings" of the students. This means that for each assignment of students into groups, they can still have a different "ordering" within each group, which would result in more than $1$ possibility. Whereas if order didn't matter, it would only be $1$ possibility for each assignment.

As such, the $420$ comes from the fact that there are $21$ spots for the first person (let's say it's Alice; it doesn't really matter), and after Alice chooses her spot, Bob has $20$ spots remaining.

The $4\cdot4\cdot3$ for the $4$ groups of $4$ case comes from the fact that there are $4$ groups of $4$ to choose from, then within that group, there are $4$ "spots" that Alice can choose (this is where the ordering part comes into play; if order didn't matter we won't have to do this). After Alice chooses her spot, there are $3$ spots left that Bob can choose.

A similar reasoning applies for the $1$ group of $5$: There is $1$ group of $5$ to choose from, and within that group, Alice has $5$ spots to choose from. After Alice chooses her spot, Bob has $4$ spots remaining to choose from, resulting in $1\cdot5\cdot4$.

Because the two cases are independent, we can then add them up to get the number of possibilities such that Alice and Bob are in the same group. Dividing that by the total number of possibilities, which is $420$, gives the final probability.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it with probabilities (as done in the answer of @user2661923) is beyond doubt the most efficient and elegant route.

Doing it with combinations you could go for:

$$\frac{\frac{19!}{2!4!4!4!5!}+\frac{19!}{4!2!4!4!5!}+\frac{19!}{4!4!2!4!5!}+\frac{19!}{4!4!4!2!5!}+\frac{19!}{4!4!4!4!3!}}{\frac{21!}{4!4!4!4!5!}}=\frac{4\times3\times4+4\times5}{20\times21}=\frac{68}{420}=\frac{17}{105}$$